# How to create reusable widgets and objects in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, uibinder

I'm working on a personal project where I have a formPanel. Inside the form panel, I have a flexTable. In which there are rows with checkboxes. In each row that is dynamically added there will be a "Clear" label at the end of the row. The label has a click handler to get the row id selected and remove it from the flex table.

However, in GWT I can only use my label instance once. So every time a new row gets added, the clear label is always dead last and non-repeatable. I would like to be able to repeat the clear, while keeping the functionality to remove its corresponding row. I'm very new at this and java so any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Ps. I'm using UiBinder to create these pages, not sure if that makes any difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widget can have only one parent. So every time you add same label instance to a new row it is removed by GWT from the previous row and inserted into a new one instead. One option would be to create one instance of label per row. You can set click handler on the table and check which cell was clicked:

```
@UiHandler("table")
void onTableClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Cell cell = table.getCellForEvent(event);
    if (cell != null) {
        int rowIndex = cell.getRowIndex();
        int cellIndex = cell.getCellIndex();
    }
}
```

Have you considered using [CellTable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html) instead of FlexTable? It should have better performance with multiple widgets in table cells.